# I am seeing my azure service bus queue getting deleted automatically

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azureservicebus

I have been attempting to create Azure service bus queue on azure portal but the queue is automatically disappearing fro portal after few hours of use.

I am creating queue manually through azure portal account. Have sufficient funds in the account. The service bus currently on Azure is in Preview mode.

I am only attempting to publish/subscribe a message from queue through the code.

Answer (score 2):

Queue could be deleted as a result of

1. Custom code that performs namespace management operations and deletes the entity.
2. [`AutoDeleteOnIdle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.autodeleteonidle.aspx) is enabled with a relatively short timespan, causing entity to be removed if it sees no action.

I suspect `AutoDeleteOnIdle` is set to a relatively low value. By default, it's [`TimeSpan.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and should not cause this issue.

Comment: Also, check that the connection is not shared with someone else. Try running on a new namespace to verify this behavior.

Comment: Sean, thanks for your response. I verified the default value for AutoDeleteOnIdle  was indeed set to default value of TimeSpan.MaxValue.

Comment: The queue still disappeared in the online azure portal. 
I had created the queue manually inside azure portal and the client / server code is only trying to send/listen to the message using the WCF NetOnewayRelayBinding.

Comment: I'll now try dropping and recreating the service bus.

Comment: Any chance to share a repro on a GitHub?

Comment: Sean, I will post the code snippets in a bit but just to update you. I left a message on the queue yesterday and also configured a queue specific SAS policy and that seem to have prevented the queue from getting lost in the cloud. Will be doing more testing to understand this provisioning/cleanup  process further.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that queue was getting recycled overnight by some nightly process at azure due to lack of some usage indication at Microsoft azure. After I configured the SAS key information at the queue level and also left a message in queue overnight I don't see the queue getting recycled any more.

Thanks to Sean Feldman for providing useful information which helped me through the process.